# В матрице имеются столбцы, в которых второй элемент больше первого. Найти сумму элементов этих столбцов

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Вот код:

```
import numpy as np

#Создаем рандомную матрицу. Размер и диапазон чисел задает пользователь
print('Enter the size of matrix:')
a = int(input('a='))
b = int(input('b='))
print('Enter the range numbers:')
startnum = int(input('start num='))
endnum = int(input('end num='))
array = np.random.randint(startnum, endnum, size=(a, b))
print('This is your matrix:\n', array)

#Сравнение второго элемента с первым в столбце
sumel=0
for i in range(array.shape(0)):
    for j in range(array.shape(1)):
        if array[i] < array[i+1]:
            sumel = array.sum(axis=0)

print(sumel)
```

#Как правильно составить алгоритм сравнения с последующим суммированием элементов столбца?
[![неработающая функция/алгоритм][1]][1]

исправил на это, но у меня индексы вылетают за пределы размера:

```
    sumel=0
for i in range(a):
    temp = array[:, i] # Получаю столбец: использую срез, где первый элемент (не указываю), второй - номер столбца
    if temp[i] < temp[i+1]:
        sumel = temp.sum(axis=0)
    if i == a-1:
        break


print(sumel)
```

[![ошибка][2]][2]

Проконсультируйте пожалуйста
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTQoI.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bSg1.png

Comment: Объясните, что значит второй элемент больше первого. Добавьте в вопрос пример.

Comment: Ошибка вызвана тем, что `.shape` - это объект, а не функция. Исправьте на `array.shape[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку это явно учебное задание, ответ будет в форме наводящих вопросов.

```
sumel=0
for i in range(array.shape(0)):
    for j in range(array.shape(1)):
        if array[i] < array[i+1]:
            sumel = array.sum(axis=0)
```

Вот вы делаете цикл по переменной `j`, а потом её никак не используете. Задумайтесь - а нужен ли вам вообще цикл в цикле. А также подумайте - какой же вам нужен цикл (один цикл, не два), по какому измерению (строки, столбцы?)

```
if array[i] < array[i+1]:
```

Что вы здесь сравниваете - строки матрицы `i` и `i+1` между собой? У вас в задании совсем не это написано.

```
sumel = array.sum(axis=0)
```

Вы суммируете всю матрицу, тут сравнения из условия никак не участвуют, индексы никакие не участвуют. Подумайте - что именно вы должны суммировать и при каком условии.

**Посмотрим обновлённый код**

```
sumel=0
for i in range(a):
    temp = array[:, i] # Получаю столбец: использую срез, где первый элемент (не указываю), второй - номер столбца
    if temp[i] < temp[i+1]:
        sumel = temp.sum(axis=0)
    if i == a-1:
        break
```

Ошибки:

- Насколько я понял, число столбцов у вас в `b`, а не в `a`, так что перебор в `for` должен быть другой.
- Зачем в проверке "второй элемент больше первого" участвует номер столбца, если вы уже получили срез по столбцу, и при этом не участвуют индексы первого и второго элемента?
- Последний `if` не нужен, вы его написали, чтобы избежать ошибки, которую я указывал выше, но он от неё не поможет.

Comment: просмотрите пожалуйста обновленный код

Comment: @user448732 Посмотрел, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
    import numpy as np

# Создаем рандомную матрицу. Размер и диапазон чисел задает пользователь
print('Enter the size of matrix:')
a = int(input('a='))
b = int(input('b='))
print('Enter the range numbers:')
startnum = int(input('start num='))
endnum = int(input('end num='))
array = np.random.randint(startnum, endnum, size=(a, b))
print('This is your matrix:\n', array)

# Проходимся по столбцам матрицы для поиска столбцов,
# в которых следующий элемент больше предыдущего
sumel = 0
for i in range(b):  # Проход по столбцам
    temp = array[:, i]  # Получаю столбец: использую срез, где первый элемент (не указываю), второй - номер столбца
    for j in range(len(temp) - 1):  # Проход по элементам столбца(нашего среза)
        if temp[j] < temp[j + 1]:  # Проверка: следующий элемент больше предыдущего?
            sumel = sum(temp, sumel)  # Суммирую элементы столбца, начиная со значения, записанного в sumel

# Вывод пользователю сумму всех столбцов, которые прошли проверку
print('Sum of element = ', sumel)
```